# FLA won't publish in CS3, previously compiled swf is gone!

Tags: debugging, flash-cs3, compilation

I have had this problem a few times lately. When I try to update & publish files that previously published fine in Flash CS3, the "Exporting Flash Movie" bar comes up, but no movie compiles. When I go to look for the swf in the Finder (Mac OS 10.5.7), it has mysteriously disappeared, and only the .FLA remains.

It doesn't happen with ALL files I publish, only some – so I know the SWF preview should come up automatically. It seems to be Actionscript-independent, as some of my files include their own AS2 code, while others simply fit in to a larger framework and have no embedded code.

I normally work off of a shared network drive, but the same thing happens on my local machine.

Has this happened to anyone else?? Is there a cache I need to clear or something?

Please help! Thanks a million :)

Comment: Another note: I checked the Publish settings to make sure I was publishing to the right place. I can see the swf show up sometimes, then disappear. I tried copying the content into a new file and the same thing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that there are corrupted fonts or library items. Someone else with the same problem mentioned that it was a corrupted image that caused the problem for them, while I discovered that it my problem is caused by a corrupted font.

**Solution:** change/reinstall the font or other corrupted item, and republish.